# JavaFX Render stage below parent

Tags: java, javafx, stage

According to the JavaFX documentation, a child stage is defined by

```
 A stage will always be on top of its parent window.
```

The issue is I'd like to render them like normal windows according to each other (if you click on one, it will render above the other). Can I do this without a hacky workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other functionality you get from making a stage a child of another stage is that the child stage is automatically closed when the parent stage is closed. You can emulate this with a listener:

```
Stage firstStage = ... ;

Stage secondStage = new Stage();

// secondStage.initOwner(firstStage);
firstStage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDDEN, evt -> secondStage.hide());

// ...
```

If you are relying on using `getOwner()` anywhere you would have to find a way around that.

(I'm not sure if this qualifies as a "hacky workaround", but it should work...).